# Can I VPN a phone's connection to my home network, and then apply my home firewall to my phones network connections?

Tags: encryption, network, linux, vpn

I have a decent firewall/router at home, and I was wondering whether it would be possible to use my home firewall for the connections that my phone makes, even when I'm not at home.

It would mean better security when connecting to open wifi networks with my phone, and more explicit control over the connections that it makes. So, assuming that my phone will have no problems with the VPN connection, would it be technically possible to:

- Make a VPN connection from my phone to my home network
- Route any connections that my phone wants to make through my home router/firewall, as if it were on my home network?

Is such a thing technically possible?

Comment: It should be, you can host a VPN server on your home network and let the phone connect to it.

Comment: @Natanael Ok, so a vpn connection to my home network (through my openvpn server) should mean that my phone's connections are treated like the phone's on my home network?

Comment: as long as the phone really does send all outgoing traffic via the VPN and don't accept incoming traffic from outside it, yes. But that's something you need to verify yourself.

Comment: @Natanael Yeah, I understand. Was just trying to see whether I'm understanding the way vpns should work correctly. But that's cool, sounds like it does exactly what I want it to do. Thanks!

Comment: it COULD do exactly that. If it does or not depends on implementation. Which is why I said you need to verify.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing both your VPN (server and client) support your desired configuration than absolutely what you're asking is technically feasible.

You'll need to configure traffic (on the server side) from clients to flow to the Internet and your client will need to tunnel all traffic and disallow local (local network where the client is) traffic to reach your client.

For more specific guidance you'll, of course, need to provide details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is definitely possible. 
Lets say you can buy a VPN service from company X and configure your phone to make all your internet communication over servers residing in the building of company X. In your case, you need to have a VPN server on your home just like the VPN server residing in Company X.

Some routers have that option. If yours do not have, you need to have a computer dedicated for that task. One raspberry pi is more than enough for that.

1. On the router, you need to configure port forwarding.
2. On the computer, you need to install a VPN server program and create a certificate.
3. On the Phone, you need to configure your home real IP adress as the VPN server and install the certificate.